# How to send a notification to a device when it connects to a WiFi network without a specific app?

Tags: ios, wifi, notifications, alert

I was staying in a hotel last week and when I connected to their WiFi network with my iPhone 4S, after agreeing on their terms and conditions (you must choose their network and it takes you automatically to the hotel's site where you agree some terms to complete the connection, many hotels charge you this way for their WiFi) a push notification trying to sell something came into my screen; this notification had "accept" and "later" buttons. Does anyone know how this happened, is it a notification launched by the website or sent directly though the WiFi network? I didn't have any apps related to the hotel which may have launched it.

This was not the kind of notifications you can look at in the notification center, it was more like a system alert.

Comment: Please don't spam your question across multiple SE sites.  Pick the best one, and post it once.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539598/send-a-notification-when-a-device-connects-to-a-wifi-network-without-an-app

Answer (score 1):

You can stop that in the future by:

Changing: File Name

```
Captive network assistant
```

to

```
No More captive network assistant
```

in `System/Library/CoreServices`

So the file is still there.

If you want to change it back just change the name back to original

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a screenshot of the message my best guess is that they were faking a system alert prompt using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Usually when you get prompted to log into a hotel's WiFi network you are sent to a web view with HTML content, so once you've logged into their network it wouldn't be hard to immediately send you to some advertising.

It could be that the hotel gets their WiFi from somewhere cheap or free, with the idea being that the WiFi provider makes their money back on adverts.